# Crunch restart session with -s symbol starting word on Linux terminal

Tags: bash

In crunch how can restart session with -s symbol starting Word: eg:

```
crunch 5 24 -f mixalpha-all-space -d 3% -d 3@ -3^ -s /aa11
```

Comment: OK, apparently `crunch` is wordlist creation program and is present in Ubuntu repositories. I removed my previous comment.  Apparently this is not related to CrunchBang Linux

Comment: Please add a little more detail: What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warnings or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety by editing your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: crunch generates wordlist but restarting session with words that starts with character such as  , <) &> (8  etc which linux uses to several operation so using them as starting character of the first point of the new crunch session will cause error. Eg if you use -s >ZZZZ linux translates  as put all command output into the file ZZZZ, if you use -s $ZZZZ is illegal because it is a $variable, And so on.